# VueJS how to filter a mapgetter array

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have the following `mapgetter` inside a component:

```
props: {
    hideSidebarText: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  },
  computed: mapGetters({
    menuItems: 'menuTypes',
  }),
```

This computed property is used to create a list:

```
<div
          class="sidebar"
          v-for="item in menuItems"
          :key="item.name"
        >
```

The list has property `hidden` that i want to filter to show only the elements where `hidden` **is false**.

How can I extend the mapGetter inside computed section so I can do the filter in my component something like this:

```
 computed: {
     menuItems: function() {
       return this.menuItems.filter(function(u) {
         return u.hidden == false
     })
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended with the following solution, dont know if is the right way to do it but make sense to me:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      menuItems: 'menuTypes'
    }),
    filteredMenuItems: function() {
      return this.menuItems.filter(function(i) {
        return i.hidden == false;
      });
    }
  },
```

Comment: If you only care for `menuTypes` in order to implement your filtered list, you could as well get rid of the `mapGetters` and instead directly access it via `this.$store.getters.menuTypes`.